# Passing one variable to another varible in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, variables, caching

I am trying to make a input table and whatever name I input into the table would be set to the variable station which would in turn be passed to the variable z.  I am not quite able to get this.  Below is my code in which I attempted to pass one variable to another.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Variables</h1>

<table width=840 align="center" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
<tr>
        <td width=40% valign="middle" align="right" nowrap> Station Name :</td>
        <td width="5%" align="center"><font color="red">(*) </font></td>
        <td align="left" nowrap>
            <input type="text" style="background-color:#EEA2A2;" id="station">
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
<p>In this example, x, y, and z are variables</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var z = document.getElementById("station");
var y = 6;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The reason why I want to pass the variable station (based on the input table) to variable z is that the value z would be cached as a value in another table.  Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the input does not have an initial value, you'll want to trigger the copy to occur on some event, such as when the focus leaves the input.  Your current code executes the copy immediately and does not wait for something to be entered into the input.

Also, you want to copy the value of the input, not the input itself.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z.value;
```

So, for example, you could do:

```
var z = document.getElementById("station");
var y = 6;
z.onblur = function() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

[Here is a Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/3wqmz14h/).